# Convert a SQL query to LINQ query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM LOC l
JOIN CLA c ON l.IdLoc = c.IdLoc
JOIN FA f on c.IdCla = f.IdCla
LEFT JOIN CON co ON f.IdCla = co.IdCla
    AND co.DeletedDate IS NULL
    AND co.IdUser = f.IdUser
WHERE f.IdUser = 7
    AND f.DeletedDate IS NULL
```

I would like to convert it to `LINQ` but I'm absolutely not at ease with `LEFT JOIN` and "temp table" with LINQ.

Moreover, I tried to convert it but it seems it is impossible to create a join clause with a `WHERE` inside in LINQ ([Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) told me that and [Linqpad](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/96/convert-sql-code-to-linq) doesn't seem able to convert from SQL to LINQ in free version)

Could you give me clue ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Linqpad does not convert SQL to LINQ, not even in the paid version.  Are you set on using Lambda syntax?  Or will sql/query syntax be OK?

Comment: I'd like a LINQ query syntax, I understand it better

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this.  I left out the select clause so that you can pull out what you need.  Things to note:

- To join multiple columns, create anonymous types.  The field names in the anonymous types must match.
- To create a `=NULL` condition, create a variable name that matches the field name in the other entity.  Set it `=null` but coerce it to the nullable data type of the field you are setting it equal to.

Edit: Updated query to move where clause to joins

```
from l in LOC
join c in CLA
   on l.IdLoc equals c.IdLoc
join f in FA
   on new     { c.IdCla, IdUser = 7, DeletedDate = (DateTime?)null }
   equals new { f.IdCla, f.IdUser, f.DeletedDate }
join co in CON
   on new     { f.IdCla, DeletedDate = (DateTime?)null, f.IdUser }
   equals new { co.IdCla, co.DeletedDate, co.IdUser } into lj
from l in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect, I upvoted it ! However, your LINQ request returns the corrects FAs, and, for each FA returned, the corresponding CON of user 7 (which is good), but also CONs linked to this FA but where CON.IdUser != 7.  
If I'm not totally clear (sorry for my English), I have the good FAs, the CONs linked to these FA but also the CONs of other users linked to these FA (and I'd only like CONs linked to user 7 in this example).